# Draw custom marker on WPF Toolkit Chart

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, charts

I have simple (x,y) graph using WPF Toolkit DataVisualisation Chart.

This is Area chart but could be line or box.

I need to show on the chart - which data point was updated last. I'd like to draw a line or show a thick gridline for that data point.

What can be done to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change code in the toolkit classes. after 4 hours of getting throught the khaos of the inheritance I finally made by adding some code into : `OrientedAxisGridLines` (to draw the line), `LinearAxis` (to calculate pixel position for the line), `DataPointSeriesWithAxes` (to have dep prop to bind to the user data).

The code is awkward and is written to get job done so I am not sharing it.

If there will be those who wants to see it - leave the comment I might do it later...